# How to find the maximum number of times that the most common item in a list appears?

Tags: python, list, counter

I want to find the number of times that the most common element in a list occurs. For example:

```
[0,0,1,2,3,0] = 3

[0,2,1,1] = 2

[0,2,1,1,0] = 2
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`'s `most_common` function, like this

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]).most_common(1)
# [(0, 3)]
```

This gives you the most commonly occuring item in the iterable. If you want just the count, you can use `max` function, like this

```
print max(Counter([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]).itervalues())
```

If you are using Python 3.x, then

```
print(max(Counter([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]).values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative;

```
a_list = [0,2,1,1]
a_list.count(max(a_list, key=a_list.count))
```

Comment: OP is asking for the most efficient way :-)